# Como exportar lineas de codigo a un archivo .sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

He creado una base de datos, en mariadb, necesito guardar en un archivo .sql mi base de datos y las lineas de codigo que use para crearla, por ejemplo si hice:

```
CREATE TABLE ejemplo (  id VARCHAR(20), x INT, PRIMARY KEY ( id,x ) FOREIGN KEY x REFERENCES otratabla(x) );
```

Lo que tengo que hacer es ademas de exportar mi base de datos, tambien las lineas de código de como la creé, con el create table, pks, fks, etc, no alcanza con crear la base y despues que el que quiera ver haga un show create table, mi objetivo es eso, crear la tabla, poner paso por paso como la hice, a eso me refiero con exportar las lineas de codigo.

El objetivo es mostrar mi manera de programar, buscando solamente encontré maneras de exportar la base en sí, y no también las líneas que usé para hacerla, o distintas consultas que necesité hacerle a la misma.

Tengo entendido que así se exporta:

mysqldump -u root -p BIBLIOTECA > biblioteca-salida.sql

---

Y respondiendo a:

> Cuando exportas la base de datos, lo que hace es: Te genera un archivo con extensión SQL y si abres ese archivo con un editor de texto y ... pum! Te encuentras con todo el código de tu bd,
>   ...
>   tablas y lo que tiene tus tablas, columnas, tipo de datos etc.,
>   ...
>   y si tienes datos ingresados también te los genera en ese mismo archivo. Entonces, ¿Qué es lo que realmente necesitas?

Bueno, si se muestra muestra como YO la cree linea por linea, ..., eso responde parte de mi consulta, tambien me gustarìa saber si hay alguna manera de guardar también en mi archivo sql, las consultas que quiera hacerle a la base, y los resultados ( tablas ) que esta devolvería.

Comment: ¿Que has investigado? Déjame decirte que aquí no se hacen tareas ni nada por el estilo, eso que dices muy fácilmente se encuentra en [internet](https://geekytheory.com/como-importarexportar-una-base-de-datos-mysql/) y en su documentación oficial.

Comment: Ramiro: Bienvenido!! No termino de entender del todo qué es lo que estás intentando hacer. ¿Podré pedirte más detalle y [edit] la pregunta para que quede más clara para todos? Por ejemplo: "*necesito exportar las lineas de codigo*" <-- ¿por qué? ¿cuál es el objetivo? ... "*codigo que usé para crear mi base*" <- ¿en dónde usaste ese código? ¿en un cliente MySQL? ¿Cuál? ... "*se puede exportar toda una base de datos*" <-- Bien, pero ¿cómo lo harías? ¿con qué método pensabas hacerlo? ¿qué tamaño tiene la base (para dimensionar a grandes rasgos)?

Comment: Perdón por no ser especifico, uso mariadb, lo que tengo que hacer es ademas de exportar mi base de datos, tambien las lineas de codigo de como la cree, con el create table, pks, fks, etc, no alcanza con crear la base y despues que el que quiera ver haga un show create table, mi objetivo es eso, crear la tabla, poner paso por paso como la hice, a eso me refiero con exportar las lineas de codigo.

Comment: Me enseñaron a exportar la base de la siguiente manera:
mysqldump -u pass -p BIBLIOTECA > biblioteca-salida.sql

Comment: @Ramiro Cuando exportas la base de datos, lo que hace es: Te genera un archivo con extensión SQL y si abres ese archivo con un editor de texto y ... pum! Te encuentras con todo el código de tu bd, es decir, desde la creación de la misma, tablas y lo que tiene tus tablas, columnas, tipo de datos etc., al exportar una base de datos lo que hace es generar todo el código y si tienes datos ingresados también te los genera en ese mismo archivo. Entonces, ¿Qué es lo que realmente necesitas?

Comment: Bueno, si al abrir al abrir el archivo con un editor de texto se muestra como YO la cree linea por linea, y no de una manera standart por el programa, eso responde parte de mi consulta, tambien me gustarìa saber si hay alguna manera de guardar tambien en mi archivo sql, las consultas que quiera hacerle a la base, y los resultados ( tablas ) que esta devolveria.

Answer (score 1):

Si interpreto correctamente tu pregunta, quieres los sentencias que te llevaron del `create database MI_BASE_DE_DATOS` al estado actual de tu DB.

Pues `mysqldump` no va a ayudarte con ello, pues va darte la foto actual de tu DB y no el paso a paso. Por ejemplo si modificaste una tabla para agregarle un columna, sólo verás creación de la tabla con todas la columnas.

Lo que quieres hacer, entiendo yo, cae en el versionado de base de datos. Lamentablemente si no has guardado los scripts que has estado ejecutando, no hay herramienta que conozca que te permita obtener lo que quieres.

Hay distintas herramientas que te facilitan la tarea, te animo a que las busques y pruebes.

Pero para mí la más sencilla de hacer y que cumple con lo que buscasm es poner los scripts SQL que vayas ejecutado y consideres útiles bajo algún sistema control de versiones. Como puede ser [git](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git),[subversion](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_(software)) o [Mercurial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial)).

Hay varias estrategias de como guardar los scripts, una muy habitual es prefijar el orden de ejecución en el nombre de los así como poner una breve descripción de lo que hace. Por ejemplo:

- `01_create_database_MiBaseDeDatos.sql`
- `02_create_table_PERSONAS.sql`
- `03_alter_table_PERSONAS_agregar_unique_index.sql`

También es habitual mantener tus scripts lo más atómicos posible (una sentencia SQL por script).

Para más detalles te aconsejo mirar el siguiente [artículo](http://www.javiergarzas.com/2014/11/versionar-bases-de-datos-2.html) o realizar una [búsqueda en Google](https://www.google.com.ar/?client=firefox-b-ab#q=control+de+versiones+de+base+de+datos&gfe_rd=cr).